# Drawing the contour line of $ z = \sqrt{xy} $ for some $z$ values by hand

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was tasked with drawing the contour lines of $ z = \sqrt{xy} $, which I find a bit problematic since I can see no way in which one can plot (by hand, and not with wolfram and others....) the $ z = \sqrt{xy} $ graph in $R^2( x-, y- $  projection} to begin with for this surface...

How can one draw this contour graph manually?

Comment: The surface does not exist in quadrants 2 and 4. At each height z the section is a rectangular hyperbola.

Answer (score 1):

Much like in two dimensions you can do it in 3 dimensions as follows:
For every point in the $x-y$ plane you calculate the $z$ coordinate by evaluating the function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{xy}$, so for every $(x,y)$ you will get the 'height'. Then you can choose any kind of representation of the coordinate system you like.

BTW: [Wolframalpha surely can do this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20z%20%3D%20sqrt%28x*y%29)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A contour line is a line on which every point on the line has the same value.

Since $\sqrt a=\sqrt b$ implies $a=b$ we find that if we take the point with coordinates $x_1$ and $y_1$, any other point on the same contour line has $x_2y_2=x_1y_1$.

So to draw contour lines for this function, for each contour line we want, choose whatever the product should be and call it $p$, now we have $x\cdot y=p$ which is equivalent to $y=\frac px$, so you can draw the graph of the function $y=\frac px$ for a few different $p$ and get a contour plot.